# Collision in Canvas with Rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[I Made a Pen](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/OvwJNw) where i have a `function Rectangle()` that creates a Rectangle and handles collision with the created Object.

But i can only get two of the Sides to work (Top and Left), the others work like reversed and pull the Sphere in on collision instead of bouncing them off, somehow i cannot figure out how to fix this.

I have been playing around with the Logic for hours now, this is the current code:

```
// Top
if (bp.y > posY - brd && bp.y < yy + brd && bp.x > posX && bp.x < xx) {
    ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.y = posY - brd;
}
// Bottom
if (bp.y > yy + brd && bp.y < posY - brd && bp.x > posX && bp.x < xx) {
    ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.y = yy + brd;
}
// Left
if (bp.x > posX - brd && bp.x < xx + brd && bp.y > posY && bp.y < yy) {
    ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.x = posX - brd;
}
// Right
if (bp.x > xx + brd && bp.x < posX - brd && bp.y > posY && bp.y < yy) {
    ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.x = xx + brd;
}
```

> On Line 116 you will find the Variables so you dont get confused by the condition.

Comment: Which rectangle is this supposed to be? The outer one, or the white square in the middle? It seems to work fine in the pen, i.e. the ball bounces off the borders of the rectangle. Also, just a tip: the convention for naming rectangle coordinates is usually `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` (which would correspond to your `posY`, `yy`, `posX`, `xx`), makes it more intuitive to read.

Comment: @MátéSafranka The inner Square is the Collider Object and it works like i said only for 2 of the sides. it never works for top and bottom or for left and right only for top/left or /bottom/right. not sure if its the detection or the handling... trying to figure it out for 5hours now.

Comment: (ignore my previous comment, I wrote that for the outer rectangle)

Comment: What's `ball.restitution`, and what's its value? When you bounce the ball off, you should multiply `ball.velocity.x` or `ball.velocity.y` by `-1` to invert the direction of movement. If `restituition` is positive, then that might be the reason.

Comment: Okay, never mind, I think I've figured it out :) Posting an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Top
if (bp.y > posY - brd && bp.y < posY && bp.x > posX && bp.x < xx) {
    ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.y = posY - brd;
}
// Bottom
if (bp.y < yy + brd && bp.y > yy && bp.x > posX && bp.x < xx) {
    ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.y = yy + brd;
}
// Left
if (bp.x > posX - brd && bp.x < posX && bp.y > posY && bp.y < yy) {
    ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.x = posX - brd;
}
// Right
if (bp.x < xx + brd && bp.x > xx && bp.y > posY && bp.y < yy) {
    ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.x = xx + brd;
}
```

Summary: in the bottom and right checks, I flipped the operator in the first clause, and changed the right operand in the second.

Comment: Thank you alot, this has resolved the unexpecting behavior, and thanks for noting the changes :) Have a nice day Sir!

Comment: No problem :) Also, one more thing: I changed the operand in the second clause for the top/left conditions as well. Generally, when I plan collision checking, I like to make a drawing of the scenario, and mark the areas where a point needs to be in order for collision to happen.

Comment: Great Tipp for beginners like me :)